# How to detect if JS origin is unaccessible?

Tags: javascript, networking

My website loads some JS file from third-party server. In some cases this server is unaccessible. Is it possible to detect such situation (for example if timeout > 200ms or 4XX response), and load JS file from another server?
Maybe jQuery can help we with it?

P.S. I can't host this JS file on own server, as it is generated dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script> 
    var loaded = false;
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"
    onload="loaded=true;" > 
</script>
```

first set a global variable to check whether js is loaded or not include your js like this .if the script is loaded , loaded variable will be `true`

Comment: Ok, thanks, this is very simple solution. But I'm looking for more complete version (if exists). Maybe it is possible to show what the best practicies - how to check variable "loaded " in cycle or by events, in order to make request to another server.

Comment: @theblackgigant - is it possible to change timeout "onerror"? It will be nice if user will not wait for seconds or minutes to load file.

Comment: @Yurik the onerror timing depends on how quick the server/browser returns an error. Which should be the preferred method in my opinion. This is because every user can have a different connection speed, so for you it can take 1 second but for me it can be 10 seconds.